# Equation of three lines forming a equilateral triangle.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

> Prove that if general equation $$\cos \left(3\alpha\right)\left(x^3 -3xy^2\right) + \sin3\alpha\left(y^3 - 3x^2y\right) + 3a\left(x^2 + y^2\right) - 4a^3 = 0$$ represents three lines then they form a equilateral triangle of area $3a^2\sqrt 3$.

---

This equation looks like an good candidate to solve in polar coordinates than in cartesian coordinates.

Converting it into polar coordinates by parts
\begin{align}
\left(x^3 -3xy^2\right) &= r^3 \left(\cos^3 \theta - 3\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta\right) =r^3 \left(4\cos^3 \theta - 3\cos \theta\right) = r^3\cos 3\theta \tag1\label1 \\
\left(y^3 - 3x^2y\right) &= r^3\left(4\sin^3 \theta - 3\sin\theta\right) = r^3\left(\cos\left(3\pi/2 - 3\theta\right)\right) = -r^3\sin 3\theta\tag2\label2
\end{align}

Using $\eqref1$, $\eqref2$
\begin{align}
r^3\left(\cos 3\alpha\cos 3\theta - \sin3\alpha\sin 3\theta\right) + 3ar^2 - 4a^3 &= 0 \\
r^3\cos \left(3\alpha+ 3\theta\right) + 3ar^2 - 4a^3 &= 0
\end{align}

On dividing by $a^3$ and substituting $z = r/a$
$$z^3\cos \left(3\alpha+ 3\theta\right) + 3z^2 - 4 = 0.$$

Now this happens very often to me, I am not able to solve this cubic for $z$.I did try to find the factor by putting $\,z = \sin\left(3\alpha + 3\theta\right),\,\tan\left(3\alpha + 3\theta\right),\,\ldots$

---

What should I do now ? how to solve this cubic ?

Comment: You might be overinterpreting the goal of the exercise, since it asks if the *assumption* that the equation "represents three lines" implies the formation of an equilateral triangle (of specified area).  While the substitution of polar coordinates seems attractive, leading in your work to a polynomial in $r/a$, I don't think you can expect to *prove* the general equation always represents three lines, nor to "solve this cubic for $a$".

Comment: Close vote for what ?  Why does ones inability to understand the question should be blamed on the question ? I think my question is very clear, please tell me if you want to rectify  anything in the question.

Comment: @hardmath No you are misinterpreting my attempt. What I did was to get the three lines that constitute the given general equation then I will use those line equations to prove that they form a equilateral triangle.

Comment: @hardmath If I am able to solve the cubic, I would be able to get those line equations. If I had already got those then what is the need of this question ?

Comment: Let me try to make the point as simply as possible.  Neither the "general equation" nor your rewrite in polar coordinates can be solved "for $a$".  Considered as a polynomial in $x,y,a$, the "general equation" is homogeneous of degree $3$, so one naturally expects that the area of any (finite) region bounded by the curve(s) will *scale* with $a$ (which is the gist of the last part of the exercise).

Comment: @hardmath No it is not homogeneous. I maybe wrong but the powers don't add upto to 3 for all terms. If you are correct then what should I answer to this question ?

Comment: Maybe my earlier comment about your polar coordinate version is easier to check by inspection. It can be rewritten as a polynomial in $r/a$.  In any case for the Cartesian coordinates we check the total degree in $x,y,a$ of all terms.

Comment: @hardmath Yes I will edit my question now to include this. still it is a 3rd degree polynomial, I still need to solve it. $a$ is a constant, why we include $a$'s power in check of homogenity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given equation always represents three lines. When we rotate the axes by an angle $\alpha$, in polar coordinates, $r$ remains unchanged but $\theta$ changes to $\theta - \alpha$. Thus the combined equation becomes
$$r^3\cos \left(3\alpha+ 3(\theta-\alpha)\right) + 3ar^2 - 4a^3 = 0$$
This is equivalent to rotating the curve clockwise by $\alpha$ about the origin and thus the shape of the curve does not change. Hence it is enough to prove that the above equation represents three lines. 
We have
\begin{align*}
r^3\cos3\theta +3ar^2 - 4a^3 &= 0\\
r^3(4\cos^3 \theta -3\cos\theta) + 3ar^2 - 4a^3 &= 0\\
4x^3 -3x(x^2+y^2)+3a(x^2+y^2) - 4a^3 &= 0\\
x^3 - 3xy^2 + 3ax^2 + 3ay^2 - 4a^3 &= 0
\end{align*}
where in the last two steps, we have converted the equation back to Cartesian. Clearly $x=a$ is a factor and dividing this out we get
$$(x-a)(x^2 - 3y^2 + 4ax + 4a^2) = 0$$
and hence
$$(x-a)((x+2a)^2 - 3y^2) = 0$$
Thus
$$(x-a)(x+2a-\sqrt{3}y)(x+2a +\sqrt{3}y) = 0$$
Now it is easy to see that the circum center of this triangle is the origin and the circum radius is $2a$. Hence the area is $3\sqrt{3}a^2$

Comment: "Now it is easy to see that the circm center of this triangle is the origin and the circum radius is 2a" how ??

Comment: The base is $x=a$ and the other vertex is $(-2a,0)$. The altitude through this vertex is the $x$ axis. Since the triangle is equilateral, centroid coincides with the circumcenter. Centroid divides the altitude in the ratio $2:1$ and hence is at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Real and imaginary parts of $ (x+iy)^3$ can be recognized here.

EDIT1:

Factorization given below *tallies fully* with the first *general* equation in OP's post.

$$ (x \cos(\alpha) - y\sin (\alpha) -a)*
(x \cos(\alpha + 2 \pi/3) - y\sin (\alpha + 2 \pi/3) -a) *
(x \cos(\alpha + 4 \pi/3) - y\sin (\alpha + 4 \pi/3) -a)=0\, \tag1 $$

Area = $ \dfrac { \sqrt3 }{4} \cdot { { (2 \sqrt3 a})^2}  = 3 \sqrt3 a^2$

The following is a plot of three  sides for $ \alpha = 12.345, a=1. $

BTW, such factorizations are useful in obtaining torsion in non-circular shafts using St. Venant's theory.

[image: 3EquilTRIA]

Comment: These are not even lines and I know what went wrong here. 1) : My equation is not homogeneous so it **may or may not** represent a triplet of lines. 2) : It will represent a triplet of lines for only special values of $a, \alpha$.

Comment: Then please delete, correct it and undelete so others do not spend time trying to prove it.

Comment: Done $\phantom{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ } $

Comment: The given equation always represents three lines. I will post a detailed solution.

Comment: @ A---B  After a night's sleep :(  found and removed a small error in plot. Rest of factorization tallies fully without considering it as any special case $\alpha=0$ by @Muralidharan.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are $r = a, \theta = -\alpha$, $r = a, \theta = \frac{2\pi}{3} - \alpha$ and $r = a, \theta = \frac{4\pi}{3} - \alpha$

Comment: How did you get these ?

Comment: It is clear now. @Muralidharan rotated it to make first line parallel to $y$ axis.